# Prisma A link table must not specify any additional scalar fields

Tags: datamodel, prisma

I have a many to many relation between two tables:

```
type Post {
  id: ID! @id
  createdAt: DateTime! @createdAt
  updatedAt: DateTime! @updatedAt
  name: String! 
  users: [Profile!] @relation(link: TABLE, name: "ParticipatedUsers")
}

type Profile {
  id: ID! @id
  createdAt: DateTime! @createdAt
  updatedAt: DateTime! @updatedAt
  name: String! 
  participatingInPosts: [Post!] @relation(name: "ParticipatedUsers")
}


type ParticipatedUsers @relationTable {
  post: Post
  profile: Profile 
  requiredPostsCount: Int
  publishedPostsCount: Int
}
```

and when trying to run the command prisma deploy i got the following errors:

> Errors:
>
> ParticipatedUsers
>       ✖ A link table must not specify any additional scalar fields.
>       ✖ A link table must not specify any additional scalar fields.
>       ✖ A link table must not specify any additional scalar fields.

how could i create a relation table and add a new fields to that table?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

In Prisma you can do this by adding a type with scalar fields and two relations to the types you want to connect, e.g.:

```
type Post {
  id: ID! @id
  createdAt: DateTime! @createdAt
  updatedAt: DateTime! @updatedAt
  name: String! 
  users: [ParticipatedUser!] @relation(link: TABLE, name: "ParticipatedUserPosts")
}

type Profile {
  id: ID! @id
  createdAt: DateTime! @createdAt
  updatedAt: DateTime! @updatedAt
  name: String! 
  participatingInPosts: [ParticipatedUser!] @relation(link: TABLE, name: "ParticipatedUserProfiles")
}


type ParticipatedUser {
  post: Post! @relation(name: "ParticipatedUserPosts")
  profile: Profile! @relation(name: "ParticipatedUserProfiles")
  requiredPostsCount: Int
  publishedPostsCount: Int
}
```